# Getting blank page using HTML publisher in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cypress, mochawesome

I am using Jenkins to run Cypress tests and using using Mochawesome to generate reports.

I am able to generate json and html results files. From the reports folder I am able to link to my test results html file and view them in the browser.

But clicking on the "Mochawesome Report" in the Jenkins job leads to a blank page, except for having a link back to job 1 and a zip link. Here is where it links to:

`http://localhost:8080/job/Job%201/Mochawesome_20Report/`

This file points to jobs/Job 1/htmlreports/Mochaweseom_20Report which has these generated files in it:
`mochawesome_06272023_160251.json` `mochawesome_06272023_160251.html`

But as I mentioned the link goes to the blank page:
[image]
[image]

Is there supposed to be a link to the HTML report on the blank page or should it just show the report?

Should index.html be added to the folder where you set it here?
[image]

I am not clear on what populates that link or how it happens, and have not found any documentation to clarify it. I appreciate your help. I have the report available but just have no clue how to correctly link to it from Jenkins.

Also I tried setting this with no luck: `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP"," ")`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> This file points to jobs/Job 1/htmlreports/Mochaweseom_20Report which
> has these generated files in it: mochawesome_06272023_160251.json
> mochawesome_06272023_160251.html

But then in your Publish HTML report config you pointed to index.html, this is most likely why this isn't working.

Try to edit the HTML Publisher config and replace `index.html` with the appropriate name of your generated html file (`mochawesome_06272023_160251.html`). If this is done correctly you should ideally see a tab for the file when you open the report in Jenkins:

[HTML reports tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKHci.png)